# custom comments form for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, theme-development, custom-field, comments

Hello everyone I am creating a theme dedicates to hotels display and booking in which I have created a custom post type 'Hotels' so now I want a mechanism to book the hotel rooms and a "book now" button in the hotel page to book the room which will send a request to the admin and also send an acknowledgement mail to the user for this I thought if I make some changes in comments form for post type hotel and display the comments form throw a [comments_popup_link();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_popup_link) and add some more meta fields throw [add_comments_meta();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_comment_meta)

---

But the question is how can I display the different custom comments(book now) requests in the admin panel with all the comments meta information related to the comments. Is it possible or do I have to think of some different mechanism to do what I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible : you can fetch the comments form the database in the admin side in the same way you would do it on the client side with [get_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments).

Now the question is : where exactly, in the admin side, do you want to display you custom comments ? You can for example create a [meta box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) in the Hotel edit page. Or you can create a single [custom admin page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus) where all the booking will be listed.

Comment: Thanks Fabien but all of the comments are listed in the comments option with the approve, edit, delete functionality so is there any way I can display those comments for the custom posts(hotel ) in the meta box under costum post type (hotel) option with same functionality to edit, delete, approve

Comment: You can do that, but not very easily. Open the wp-admin/edit-comments.php file and study the PHP code : you should find all what you need.